# socket.gaierror: [Ernno 1104]

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a IP resolver for a website by using gethostbyname and this is the error I get:

```
File "wexec.py", line 39, in hell
  ipname = socket.gethostbyname('http://%s') % (hcon)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

I have attempted to fix it and I tried putting ('www.youtube.com') and then it worked. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. but here is my code:

```
def hell():

    hcon = raw_input(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "Website: ")
    urlopen = urllib2.urlopen('http://%s:80' % (hcon))  
    ipname = socket.gethostbyname('http://%s') % (hcon)
    print(strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", gmtime()) + " Found IP: %s " % (ipname))
    enter = raw_input("Press enter or any other key to continue.")

hell()
```

So what do I do? can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, your bracketing is slightly off. Rather than:

```
ipname = socket.gethostbyname('http://%s') % (hcon)
```

it should be:

```
ipname = socket.gethostbyname('http://%s' % (hcon))
```

By closing the call to `gethostbyname` early, you prevented the `%s` string formatting from taking place, meaning that the name contained the *literal* `%s` rather than the value of `hcon`.

I'm also not sure that you should be including `http://` in your host name either. A hostname is not the same as a URL. You probably want to remove the URL type from the front, in which case you may as well simplify it to:

```
ipname = socket.gethostbyname(hcon)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
ipname = socket.gethostbyname('http://%s') % (hcon)
```

You're passing `"http://%s"` to `gethostbyname`

Try this:

```
ipname = socket.gethostbyname('http://%s' % hcon)
```

Comment: `http://www.youtube.com` is a URL, not a host name. The host name part of it is `www.youtube.com`, and is the part that `socket.gethostbyname()` wants to see...